# String object creation for concatenated results

Tags: java, string, concatenation, string-literals

When I create  code like this:

```
String s ="hello";
String s1= new String("bye");
String s3=s1.concat(s);
String s4 = s.concat(s1);
```

Here `s` is in literal, `s1` is in heap. When I concatenate both and create a new object, where will it be created (in heap or intern?)

Here one is in pool and one is in heap.

Answer (score 1):

If you see the [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.concat%28java.lang.String%29) of `concat()` method you will see that it return a new string

```
return new String(0, count + otherLen, buf);
```

So string is created in heap

Answer (score 0):

`String concat()` will return an new `String` Object not a literal.
 SO, it will be where the object's are stored, As you said it should be `heap`.

new object creation is specified in the doc

**....a new String object is created,** representing a character sequence that.......